# Somehow the searchbar in Genius is not working

Tags: python, selenium, discord.py

I am using Selenium to access the web with python.
And i am using discord.py to put this into a discord bot.
I don't know if the problem is at selenium or discord.py but i cannot put discord.message intothe code. When I do that, i get an error:

I hope you can help me with that

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\selko\PycharmProjects\shosch\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\selko\PycharmProjects\shosch\aternoscommand.py", line 36, in lyrics
    search_bar_ge.send_keys(message)
  File "C:\Users\selko\PycharmProjects\shosch\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "C:\Users\selko\PycharmProjects\shosch\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'module' has no len()

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\selko\PycharmProjects\shosch\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\selko\PycharmProjects\shosch\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\selko\PycharmProjects\shosch\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object of type 'module' has no len()
```

and this is the full code:

```
import time

from discord import guild, message
from discord.ext import commands
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, ui
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

search_bar_ge = ''
gesemessage = ''
cookiege = ''


class geniuscommand(commands.Cog):
def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    print("der geniuscommand ist ready")

@commands.command()
async def lyrics(self, ctx):
    global search_bar_ge
    global cookiege
    global gesemessage
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/selko/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
    waitge = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    driver.get("https://genius.com")
    print(message)
    cookiege = waitge.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    search_bar_ge = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    search_bar_ge.send_keys(message)
    search_bar_ge.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(geniuscommand(client))
```

Comment: Why would you even want to put `discord.message` in there? What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: I am Trying to do a command, its like -lyrics songname.
And i want, that it searches this songname.
So `search_bar_ge.send_keys(message)`, and the `disdcord.message` is the songname.

Comment: `discord.message` is a module, I think you're looking for arguments, take a look at the [commands introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters)

Comment: but message.content doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Where do you see `message.content` in the link I gave?